# Click event for radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

how to write action for when an ASP.NET/C# radio button check was changed?
I need a pop up to be opened when radio button is clicked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the Condition on the OnCheckedChanged Event:

```
   if(radiobutton.Checked)
   {
      // Place your code for POPUP
      mpeQCAttribute.Show();           // mpeQCAttribute is the ModalPopupExtender
   }
```

Comment: did u set AutoPostBack property is true.

Comment: how to turn on AutoPostBack property?

Comment: @Karthik. It can be done in code behind like radiobutton.AutoPostBack=true or in your aspx file like this: 
<asp:radiobutton id="radioButton" runat="server" autopostback="true" />

Comment: yes! I turned it on but when I click on radiobutton page is reloading but no action is taking place

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(function(){
   $("input:radio").change(function(){
       var selectdValue = $("input:radio:checked").val();
       window.open("myPopup.aspx?val=" + selectdValue ,"myPopup");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to bind javascript's popup with radiobuttons in itemdatabound/rowdatabound events. alternatively u can use jquery. using jquery it's easy, just explore that